# multiprocessing with lisp, let*

Tags: multiprocessing, common-lisp, ccl

I am trying to create a process that uses a `let*`. When I try to run it, the child process is in a [reset] state. If I use a workaround and use `let`, the thread starts out as [active] everything works fine.

I am puzzled at this behavior and would love an explanation.

```
(defparameter *g* 1)
(defparameter *res-list* nil)

(defun tester ()
  (let ((res *g*))
    (push res *res-list*)))

CL-USER> (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(4856) [Active] #x3020036E30AD>
CL-USER> *res-list*
(1)
```

Everything works so far. But if I change the let to let*, I get a [reset] state, but the code within the child thread is executed.

```
(defun tester ()
  (let* ((res *g*))
    (push res *res-list*)))

CL-USER> (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(4862) [Reset] #x3020036BCF2D>
CL-USER> *res-list*
(1 1)
```

I would also be thankful if someone could point me to a resource which would explain the different states.

Thanks.

Comment: `let*` and `let` are identical when you are binding a single variable; you can verify it with `disassemble`; also, in your case there is no reason to bind `res` at all; `disassemble` should show that your code is equivalent to `(push *g* *res-list*)`

Comment: I think that this is probably just a one-off occurrence.  The process doesn't have much to do, so it probably doesn't last very long.  When you got one with "Active", maybe you caught it before it was finished.  When I run your first code, I'm getting "Reset".  I haven't been able to catch an "Active" yet.

Comment: This is a race condition between the process running to completion and the P part of the REPL printing the process.  You shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different results are not because of `let` and `let*`.  Processes can be in different states, and you're just seeing different results based on when you're catching the process to print it. When I run your code at the command line, I get mostly "Reset", but also some "Exhausted" and "Dead".

```
$ ccl64 
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7-r14925M  (LinuxX8664)!
? (defparameter *g* 1)
*G*
? (defparameter *res-list* nil)
*RES-LIST*
? (defun tester ()
    (let ((res *g*))
      (push res *res-list*)))
TESTER
? (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(2) [Exhausted] #x30200058FDBD>
? (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(3) [Reset] #x30200058CB3D>
? (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(4) [Reset] #x30200058AB3D>
? (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(7) [Dead] #x302000584B3D>
? (ccl:process-run-function "test" 'tester)
#<PROCESS test(8) [Reset] #x302000582B3D>
```

The manual doesn't say a whole lot about these different states, as far as I can tell, but it does have this, which should be enough to get you digging into other parts of the manual:

> #### [7.3.2.  As of August 2003:](http://ccl.clozure.com/ccl-documentation.html#Implementation-Decisions-and-Open-Questions)
>
> - It's not clear that exposing PROCESS-SUSPEND/PROCESS-RESUME is a good idea: it's not clear that they offer ways to win, and it's clear
>     that they offer ways to lose.
> - It has traditionally been possible to reset and enable a process that's "exhausted" . (As used here, the term "exhausted" means that
>     the process's initial function has run and returned and the underlying
>     native thread has been deallocated.) One of the principal uses of
>     PROCESS-RESET is to "recycle" threads; enabling an exhausted process
>     involves creating a new native thread (and stacks and synchronization
>     objects and ...),and this is the sort of overhead that such a
>     recycling scheme is seeking to avoid. It might be worth trying to
>     tighten things up and declare that it's an error to apply
>     PROCESS-ENABLE to an exhausted thread (and to make PROCESS-ENABLE
>     detect this error.)
> - When native threads that aren't created by Clozure CL first call into lisp, a "foreign process" is created, and that process is given
>     its own set of initial bindings and set up to look mostly like a
>     process that had been created by MAKE-PROCESS. The life cycle of a
>     foreign process is certainly different from that of a lisp-created
>     one: it doesn't make sense to reset/preset/enable a foreign process,
>     and attempts to perform these operations should be detected and
>     treated as errors.